# Как при открытии .exe файла убрать открывающееся окно командной строки?

Tags: python

есть программа, скомпилированная далее в .exe файл с помощью pyinstaller
код программы:

```
import tkinter
import sys
import os
import time
time.sleep(30)
path = sys.argv[0]
file_name = path.split('\\')[-1]
startup_path = '"%Appdata%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\"'

os.system(f'copy {path} {startup_path}') # копируем себя
master = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master, bg='blue', height=300, width=600)
canvas.pack()
master.mainloop()
#тут при опред. условиях удаляется из автозапуска
os.system(f'del {startup_path+file_name}')
```

компилировал путем `pyinstaller -F main.py`, то есть чтобы собрало все в один файл без кучи рядом библиотек, но при нажатии открывается такое окошко, а потом оно исчезает и появляется уже программа, суть в том что у меня еще стоит таймер и это окошко высвечивается 30 секунд(как по таймеру):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно скомпилировать без этого окна путем `pyinstaller -w main.py`, но будет рядом с файлом.exe  куча библиотек и поэтому не работает добавление и удаление из автозапуска

как можно это окошко убрать в коде? или как нибудь по другому?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте ключи `-F` и `-w` вместе:
`pyinstaller -F -w main.py`